# Flavor and Chemical Composition of Thyme

Tags: flavor, spices, chemistry

What is the flavor of Thyme?  What chemicals give it this flavor?

Answer (score 4):

Thyme is dominated by the **phenolic compound thymol**, with the **terpenes pinene, cymene, and linalool** adding additional pine, citrus, and flowery flavors, respectively.

Source: On Food and Cooking (revised edition), pp 391, and table on 392.  If you're into the chemistry of flavor, I highly suggest buying a copy, because the same table lists main flavor compounds for dozens of common ingredients and flavorings.